# How to apply attributes to a single column of a tabular excluding one cell

Tags: tables

I am using this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{array}% actually already loaded by `collcell`
\newcommand*{\mymacro}[1]{\fbox{#1}}% Do anything you like with `#1`
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\mymacro}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{Cc}
  TestA  & A longer test cell \\
  \empty & The new version supports 'verb'! \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

, to apply some attributes to a single column. Is there a way to escape this for one cell (e.g. the top cell) of that column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `\multicolumn` that is easy:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{array, makecell, xcolor}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\color{Crimson!60!}}% actually already loaded by `collcell`
\newcommand*{\mymacro}[1]{\fbox{#1}}% Do anything you like with `#1`
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\mymacro}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{Cc}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{First Head}} & \thead{Second Head}\\
  TestA & A longer test cell \\
  \empty & The new version supports 'verb'! \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]